# Factor Analysis on Tweets using R. Error

Tags: r, twitter, text-mining, factor-analysis

I'm new to R and factor Analysis. The case I was trying to do was a text mining on twitter and using factanal function to reduce the term into factors.
I manage to retrieve the tweets, put it in csv, and making a term document Matrix out of it.

Here is the specific code I was trying to do:

```
tweetsTestRaw<-read.csv(filename,header=T)
tweetsTest<-clean_text(tweetsTestRaw$text) #my custom text cleaning function
tweetsTest.corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(as.vector(tweetsTest)))
tweetsTest.matrix <- t(TermDocumentMatrix(tweetsTest.corpus,control = list(wordLengths=c(4,Inf))));
d = as.matrix(tweetsTest.matrix)
d_stan = as.data.frame(scale(d))
res1a = factanal(d_stan, factors = 2, rotation = "varimax", na.action = na.omit) #error
```

Here is a small part on what my term document matrix looks like:

[image: My term document matrix]

after executing the factanal() function, it always give the error:

```
Error in solve.default(cv) : 
Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[6,6] = 0
```

I search through the internet about this error. None talking about using factor analysis on tweets. Some people talking about the data fault on different case but nobody provide me with a solution on what I should do. 
I don't really understand factor analysis. So if someone suggest me to do something with the data, I hope you can provide code on how to do that.

Comment: Perhaps your data is zero inflated and thus causing you problems? A thought: https://genomebiology.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s13059-015-0805-z

Comment: @RomanLuštrik perhaps you are right. I might try to checking out R package for ZIFA method for now.

Comment: I can't find any R package for ZIFA :( I might need help for custom R code..